# Can I deploy a contract using the MetaMask console and if so, how?

Tags: dapp-development

Can I deploy a contract using the MetaMask console and if so, how?

Hi there,

I recently started testing the MetaMask console from Chrome (web3).

Is it possible to deploy a contract using the console only and if so, how would I go about it?

Something like this?

```
var contractInstance = MyContract.new([contructorParam1] [, contructorParam2], {data: '0x12345...', from: myAccount, gas: 1000000});
```

Can I deploy a contract from my local laptop as a text file?

Tera

Answer (score 10):

To deploy a contract through web3, you need first the ABI (Application Binary Interface).

You can compile (get the ABI) with Javascript and the Web3 library

```
var contractSource = "" + 
    "contract test {\n" +
    "   function multiply(uint a) returns(uint d) {\n" +
    "       return a * 7;\n" +
    "   }\n" +
    "}\n";

var contractCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(contractSource);

var code = contractCompiled.code;
var abi = contractCompiled.info.abiDefinition;
```

Then, you can deploy a new contract using this code and it will return the contract address.

```
var contract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
contract.new(
   {
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
     data: code, 
     gas: '4700000'
   }, function (e, contract){
      console.log(e, contract);
      if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
       }
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you constructor has arguments:

```
var contract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
contract.new(arg1, arg2,
   {
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
     data: code, 
     gas: '4700000'
   } 
(...)
```

---

Once deployed, you can access to the contract methods:

```
web3.eth.contract(abi).at(address).multiply(2, function(err, result){ 
    console.log(err);
    console.log(result); // Supposed to return 7*2=14
});
```

Otherwise, [Solidy Browser](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-v0.4.7+commit.822622cf.js) is a great tool to make it easier:

[image]

And for more productive and professional tools, I advice [Truffle](https://github.com/ConsenSys/truffle) that will provide command lines to compile, deploy/migrate, automate tests and serve (web server). Truffle will also inject a library on the top of web3 to integrate some contract variables, kind of shortcuts instead of playing all the time with the ABI...

Comment: This answer doesn't say where to put constructor arguments, such as constructorParam1 and 2 in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I updated my answer to include the case when the constructor has arguments.

Comment: Above link goes to the old version of the Solidity compiler. New link here: https://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false&version=soljson-v0.5.1+commit.c8a2cb62.js