# undefined contract address when trying to deploy with web3 and Metamask

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-deployment, remix, metamask

I am trying to develop a simple wallet type contract but having troubles deploying it. I am trying to deploy it using the method described [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11048/can-i-deploy-a-contract-using-the-metamask-console-and-if-so-how). I am using truffle and web3 along with Metamask. Now, here's what I have for deploying the contract:

```
var contract = web3.eth.contract(abi);

instance = contract.new({
          from: web3.eth.accounts[0],
          data: <bytecode>,
          gas: 10000000
      }, function (e, contract){
          console.log(e, contract);
          if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
              console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
          }
      });
```

Transaction goes through fine but the contract address remains `undefined` for some reason. I want to be able to call contract functions. I have tried deploying it straight from Browser-Solidity with no luck.

Can anyone help me figure out what's going on? Also, is there any better way of doing this? Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: There's a little more context that would help here. How are you creating the contract instance?

Comment: Ah yes, forgot about that. Added now. I am using what is described on the [wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract) and [other places](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11048/can-i-deploy-a-contract-using-the-metamask-console-and-if-so-how). I get two callbacks, in the first one transaction hash and address both are `undefined` and in the second one, only address is `undefined`. On the docs it says that the address should be defined in the second callback but that's not working for me.